# Rspec - capybara::ElementNotFound:Unable to find field "name"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara

So I am having a bit of a struggle with the rspec errors I am getting. I have a column in my database for name, so I am not sure why that wouldn't work... The error reads-

```
failures:

1) Sammiches GET /sammiches creates a new sammich
 Failure/Error: fill_in 'name', :with => 'lechuga'
 Capybara::ElementNotFound:
   Unable to find field "name"
 # ./spec/requests/sammiches_spec.rb:13:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Failure with line non commented out.

```
1) Sammiches GET /sammiches creates a new sammich
 Failure/Error: visit sammiches_path
 ActionView::Template::Error:
   undefined method `sammich' for #<Sammich:0x007ff33b5594f8>
```

spec file -

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Sammiches" do
 describe "GET /sammiches" do
it "display some sammiches" do
    @sammich = Sammich.create :name => 'bacon'
    visit sammiches_path
    page.should have_content 'bacon'
end

it "creates a new sammich" do
    visit sammiches_path
    fill_in 'name', :with => 'lechuga'
    click_button 'create Sammich'

    current_path.should = sammich_path
    page.should have_content 'BLT'

    save_and_open_page
  end
   end
    end
```

My view look like. The strange thing is it only "works" if I get rid of that commented part. Any help on that would be great as well-

```
<h1>All my Sammiches</h1>
<%= form_for Sammich.new do |f| %>
<%= f.label :sammich %>
#<%= f.text_field :sammich %>#
<%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
  <ul>
<% for sammich in @sammiches %>
<li><%= sammich.name %></li>

<% end %>
 </ul>
```

Thanks!

page source

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Action Controller: Exception caught</title>
  <style>
    body { background-color: #fff; color: #333; }

    body, p, ol, ul, td {
      font-family: helvetica, verdana, arial, sans-serif;
      font-size:   13px;
      line-height: 18px;
    }

    pre {
      background-color: #eee;
      padding: 10px;
      font-size: 11px;
      white-space: pre-wrap;
    }

    a { color: #000; }
    a:visited { color: #666; }
    a:hover { color: #fff; background-color:#000; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>
  NoMethodError in
  Sammiches#index
</h1>

<p>
  Showing <i>/Users/Cameron/sammy/sammiches/app/views/sammiches/index.html.erb</i> where line <b>#4</b> raised:
  <pre><code>undefined method `sammich&#x27; for #&lt;Sammich:0x007fac4169d300&gt;</code></pre>
</p>

<p>Extracted source (around line <b>#4</b>):
<pre><code>1: &lt;h1&gt;All my Sammiches&lt;/h1&gt;
2: &lt;%= form_for Sammich.new do |f| %&gt;
3: &lt;%= f.label :sammich %&gt;
4: &lt;%= f.text_field :sammich %&gt;
5: &lt;%= f.submit %&gt;
6: &lt;% end %&gt;
7: &lt;ul&gt;
</code></pre></p>

<p></p>


<p><code>Rails.root: /Users/Cameron/sammy/sammiches</code></p>

<div id="traces">
    <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById(&#x27;Framework-Trace&#x27;).style.display=&#x27;none&#x27;;document.getElementById(&#x27;Full-Trace&#x27;).style.display=&#x27;none&#x27;;document.getElementById(&#x27;Application-Trace&#x27;).style.display=&#x27;block&#x27;;; return false;">Application Trace</a> |
    <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById(&#x27;Application-Trace&#x27;).style.display=&#x27;none&#x27;;document.getElementById(&#x27;Full-Trace&#x27;).style.display=&#x27;none&#x27;;document.getElementById(&#x27;Framework-Trace&#x27;).style.display=&#x27;block&#x27;;; return false;">Framework Trace</a> |
    <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById(&#x27;Application-Trace&#x27;).style.display=&#x27;none&#x27;;document.getElementById(&#x27;Framework-Trace&#x27;).style.display=&#x27;none&#x27;;document.getElementById(&#x27;Full-Trace&#x27;).style.display=&#x27;block&#x27;;; return false;">Full Trace</a> 

    <div id="Application-Trace" style="display: block;">
      <pre><code>app/views/sammiches/index.html.erb:4:in `block in _app_views_sammiches_index_html_erb__208297745638609695_70188865290640&#x27;
app/views/sammiches/index.html.erb:2:in `_app_views_sammiches_index_html_erb__208297745638609695_70188865290640&#x27;</code></pre>
    </div>
    <div id="Framework-Trace" style="display: none;">
      <pre><code>activemodel (3.2.13) lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:407:in `method_missing&#x27;
activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:149:in `method_missing&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:1159:in `value_before_type_cast&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:1147:in `value_before_type_cast&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:1041:in `block in to_input_field_tag&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:1041:in `fetch&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:1041:in `to_input_field_tag&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:690:in `text_field&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:1284:in `text_field&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:40:in `block in capture&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:187:in `with_output_buffer&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:40:in `capture&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:378:in `form_for&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render&#x27;
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:125:in `instrument&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:47:in `block (2 levels) in render_template&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `block in instrument&#x27;
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument&#x27;
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument&#x27;
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `instrument&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:46:in `block in render_template&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:54:in `render_with_layout&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:45:in `render_template&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:18:in `render&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:36:in `render_template&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:17:in `render&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:110:in `_render_template&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:225:in `_render_template&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:103:in `render_to_body&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:28:in `render_to_body&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/compatibility.rb:50:in `render_to_body&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:88:in `render&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `block (2 levels) in render&#x27;
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:5:in `block in ms&#x27;
/Users/Cameron/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:295:in `realtime&#x27;
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:5:in `ms&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `block in render&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:83:in `cleanup_view_runtime&#x27;
activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:24:in `cleanup_view_runtime&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:39:in `render&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_render&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:5:in `send_action&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action&#x27;
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:414:in `_run__3460368674634880969__process_action__2573647100002742481__callbacks&#x27;
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback&#x27;
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks&#x27;
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action&#x27;
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument&#x27;
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument&#x27;
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:207:in `process_action&#x27;
activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:36:in `call&#x27;
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call&#x27;
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each&#x27;
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:612:in `call&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call&#x27;
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call&#x27;
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call&#x27;
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:210:in `context&#x27;
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `call&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:341:in `call&#x27;
activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call&#x27;
activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:479:in `call&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call&#x27;
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__2328833785069737987__call__85209834340556796__callbacks&#x27;
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback&#x27;
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks&#x27;
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in `call&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call&#x27;
railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app&#x27;
railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call&#x27;
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged&#x27;
railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call&#x27;
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call&#x27;
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call&#x27;
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call&#x27;
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:63:in `call&#x27;
railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call&#x27;
railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call&#x27;
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call&#x27;
railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call&#x27;
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service&#x27;
/Users/Cameron/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service&#x27;
/Users/Cameron/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run&#x27;
/Users/Cameron/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread&#x27;</code></pre>
    </div>
    <div id="Full-Trace" style="display: none;">
      <pre><code>activemodel (3.2.13) lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:407:in `method_missing&#x27;
activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:149:in `method_missing&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:1159:in `value_before_type_cast&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:1147:in `value_before_type_cast&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:1041:in `block in to_input_field_tag&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:1041:in `fetch&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:1041:in `to_input_field_tag&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:690:in `text_field&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:1284:in `text_field&#x27;
app/views/sammiches/index.html.erb:4:in `block in _app_views_sammiches_index_html_erb__208297745638609695_70188865290640&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:40:in `block in capture&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:187:in `with_output_buffer&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:40:in `capture&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:378:in `form_for&#x27;
app/views/sammiches/index.html.erb:2:in `_app_views_sammiches_index_html_erb__208297745638609695_70188865290640&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render&#x27;
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:125:in `instrument&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:47:in `block (2 levels) in render_template&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `block in instrument&#x27;
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument&#x27;
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument&#x27;
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `instrument&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:46:in `block in render_template&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:54:in `render_with_layout&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:45:in `render_template&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:18:in `render&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:36:in `render_template&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:17:in `render&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:110:in `_render_template&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:225:in `_render_template&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:103:in `render_to_body&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:28:in `render_to_body&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/compatibility.rb:50:in `render_to_body&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:88:in `render&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `block (2 levels) in render&#x27;
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:5:in `block in ms&#x27;
/Users/Cameron/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:295:in `realtime&#x27;
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:5:in `ms&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `block in render&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:83:in `cleanup_view_runtime&#x27;
activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:24:in `cleanup_view_runtime&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:39:in `render&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_render&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:5:in `send_action&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action&#x27;
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:414:in `_run__3460368674634880969__process_action__2573647100002742481__callbacks&#x27;
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback&#x27;
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks&#x27;
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action&#x27;
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument&#x27;
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument&#x27;
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:207:in `process_action&#x27;
activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:36:in `call&#x27;
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call&#x27;
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each&#x27;
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:612:in `call&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call&#x27;
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call&#x27;
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call&#x27;
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:210:in `context&#x27;
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `call&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:341:in `call&#x27;
activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call&#x27;
activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:479:in `call&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call&#x27;
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__2328833785069737987__call__85209834340556796__callbacks&#x27;
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback&#x27;
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks&#x27;
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in `call&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call&#x27;
railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app&#x27;
railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call&#x27;
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged&#x27;
railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call&#x27;
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call&#x27;
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call&#x27;
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call&#x27;
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call&#x27;
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:63:in `call&#x27;
railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call&#x27;
railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call&#x27;
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call&#x27;
railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call&#x27;
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service&#x27;
/Users/Cameron/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service&#x27;
/Users/Cameron/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run&#x27;
/Users/Cameron/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread&#x27;</code></pre>
    </div>
</div>



<h2 style="margin-top: 30px">Request</h2>
<p><b>Parameters</b>: <pre>None</pre></p>

<p><a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('session_dump').style.display='block'; return false;">Show session dump</a></p>
<div id="session_dump" style="display:none"><pre>_csrf_token: &quot;wsS7/d0sPVMEvPA2DIO1uJgLEhwH38/ckvq14iZZoxw=&quot;
session_id: &quot;a72797cacd094ecd4b6e57ece26e1ef2&quot;</pre></div>

<p><a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('env_dump').style.display='block'; return false;">Show env dump</a></p>
<div id="env_dump" style="display:none"><pre>GATEWAY_INTERFACE: &quot;CGI/1.1&quot;
HTTP_ACCEPT: &quot;text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8&quot;
HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET: &quot;ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3&quot;
HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING: &quot;gzip,deflate,sdch&quot;
HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE: &quot;en-US,en;q=0.8&quot;
HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL: &quot;max-age=0&quot;
REMOTE_ADDR: &quot;127.0.0.1&quot;
REMOTE_HOST: &quot;localhost&quot;
SERVER_NAME: &quot;localhost&quot;
SERVER_PROTOCOL: &quot;HTTP/1.1&quot;</pre></div>


<h2 style="margin-top: 30px">Response</h2>
<p><b>Headers</b>: <pre>None</pre></p>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why don't you want the line commented out? What is your question specifically? You know why it doesn' work, because `<%= f.text_field :sammich %>` is commented out.

Comment: Sorry, that first error I put was with the line out. I have just added the error with the line in.

Comment: What does your page source look like when you visit the page?

Comment: I updated my answer with an actual answer. Let me know how it turns out for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might get downvoted for this but it's difficult to explain on a comment. There is absolutely no need to do

```
<% for sammich in @sammiches %>
  <li><%= sammich.name %></li>
<% end %>
```

Instead you should do

```
<% @sammiches.each do |sammich| %>
  <li><%= sammich.name %></li>
<% end %>
```

As for why your code isn't working, the `form_for` tag helps you fill in your attributes of your record, inserts it into parameters, and sends it to the create action. But what really matters in your case is that you don't have an attribute named `Sammich` for the `Sammich` model. You do however have an attribute named `name`. So what do you do?

```
<%= form_for Sammich.new do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :sammich %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot more sense. I added the page source to the original post.

Comment: Glad it works for you! Remember to check off the question that solves your problem.